# Java binarySearch using custom function

Tags: java, function-pointers, binary-search

Is it possible in Java to run a binarySearch on a function of the elements, not the elements themselves?

In other words binary search on f(A[i]), not on A[i].

For example consider this array: [1, 3, 4, 5, 9].
The goal is to find the first element whose square is greater than or equal to 20. (In this case the answer is 5).

Can we achieve this in Java with its binarySearch implementation (and not writing our own binary search)?

I saw there is a version binarySearch which takes a comparator, but I am not sure if it's guaranteed that the first element in comparison would be the element from the array, and the second element would be the target?

```
binarySearch(T[] a, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Also please note "square" is just an example, which has a reverse square root. But in general assume there is no reverse function. ie we want to apply the function on the elements for the binary search.

Another note: Assume the array is sorted, and f(i) is increasing.

Comment: Well, I think I found a solution.  Please check the answer and let me know. I added additional information in the answer to explain how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, which is slightly tricky (hacky).

However I think considering the fact that Java's BinarySearch returning the `(-(insertion point) - 1)` when the element is not the array, it's a fair game.

The idea is to distinguish the target by for example negating it, so in the compare function if the number is negative we know it's the target (and negate it), and if it's positive it's an array element and we should apply the function.

This is based on the assumption that there is no negative number in the array. If there are negative numbers this method doesn't work.

Here is the code for the example in the question:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class BinarySearchFx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = {1, 3, 4, 5, 9};
        Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> x*x;
        Comparator<Integer> comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
            o1 = o1 > 0? f.apply(o1) : -o1;
            o2 = o2 > 0? f.apply(o2) : -o2;
            return o1 - o2;
        };

        int result = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, -20, comparator);
        if (result < 0)
            result = -result - 1;
        System.out.printf("index: %d, element: %d", result, arr[result]); // prints index: 3, element: 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. According to the documentation:

> The method returns the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise,
>  `(-(insertion point) - 1)`. The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or `list.size()` if all elements in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

So by adjusting the returned index you can get the next value (or even previous value) nearest the location where the desired value would have been found.

This works as follows:

- generate a `list` of values  of 1 to 20.  Call then `n`
- create a lambda, `fn` to apply to each n.
- create a `Comparator<Integer> comp` which uses `fn` for comparison
- invoke the binarySort using `list`, `n`, and `comp`
- use the returned index to find the nearest `n` for `f(n)`

Here is an example that returns the nearest value to `f(n)`

```
    Random r = new Random(23);
        // define f(n)
        Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> x*x + 2 * x + 3;

        Comparator<Integer> comp =
                (a, b) -> Integer.compare(f.apply(a), f.apply(b));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // generate a list of f(n) values.
            List<Integer> list = r.ints(10, 1, 20).distinct()
                    .sorted().boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<Integer> fns = list.stream().map(f::apply).collect(Collectors.toList());
            // Choose a random n
            int n = r.nextInt(20);

            System.out.println("fns = " + fns);
            System.out.println("n = " + list);

            // now find nearest f(n) in the list.
            int fn = f.apply(n);
            System.out.println("searching for nearest value to f(" + n
                    + ")   [" + fn + "]");

            int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, n, comp);

            // Now determine the index of the value that
            // meets the requirements.
            if (index >= 0) {
                System.out
                        .println("Exact answer = " + list.get(index));
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                int nearest;
                index = -index - 1;
                // check end cases
                if (index == 0) {
                    nearest = list.get(index);
                } else if (index == list.size()) {
                    nearest = list.get(index - 1);
                } else {
                    // check middle cases
                    int lowerValue = list.get(index - 1);
                    int higherValue = list.get(index);
                    if (n - lowerValue > higherValue - n) {
                        nearest = higherValue;
                    } else {
                        nearest = lowerValue;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(
                        "Nearest result to " + n + " is " + nearest);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Prints:

```
fn = [18, 51, 66, 83, 102, 123, 171, 291, 363]
n = [3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18]
searching for nearest value to f(14)   [227]
Nearest result to 14 is 12

fn = [6, 11, 38, 51, 83, 198, 326]
n = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 13, 17]
searching for nearest value to f(17)   [326]
Exact answer = 17

fn = [11, 18, 83, 146, 171, 227, 291, 326]
n = [2, 3, 8, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17]
searching for nearest value to f(0)   [3]
Nearest result to 0 is 2

fn = [6, 18, 27, 51, 66, 198, 363]
n = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 13, 18]
searching for nearest value to f(1)   [6]
Exact answer = 1

fn = [11, 18, 66, 102, 146, 198, 258, 291, 326]
n = [2, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17]
searching for nearest value to f(0)   [3]
Nearest result to 0 is 2
```

Comment: The issue is that for target we have the value of target, not the reverse of it.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, if you pass the target value, the `Comparator` will apply whatever function has been incorporated so it would compute `f(f(n))`.  And if you didn't put `f(n)` in the `Comparator` you would have other problems.  But it was interesting to work on.  binary searches aren't that difficult to write so that may be the way to go.  I am out of ideas.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible, check this out:

```java
package control;

import java.util.Comparator;

class Testing {
    int a;
    String b;
    Testing(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public class FunctionalBinarySearch {

    private static <T> int binarySearch(T[] array, T t, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        int l = 0, r = array.length - 1, m;
        while (l <= r) {
            m = l + (r - l) / 2;
            if (c.compare(array[m], t) == 0) return m;
            if (c.compare(array[m], t) < 0) l = m + 1;
            else if (c.compare(array[m], t) > 0) r = m - 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing[] test = new Testing[]{
                new Testing(1, "a"),
                new Testing(2, "b"),
                new Testing(3, "c"),
                new Testing(4, "d")
        };

        System.out.println(binarySearch(test, new Testing(3, "xyz"),
                //This lambda is applied as a search criteria function
                Comparator.comparingInt(testing -> testing.a)));

        //Uses the string comparator
        System.out.println(binarySearch(test, new Testing(1, "d"),
                Comparator.comparing(testing -> testing.b)));
    }

}
```

#### Notes

- This binary search algorithm needs the input array to be ordered.
- It requires to specify a comparator each call.
- It returns the index of the object if any and -1 if none.
- The comparator describes a *search criteria* it is a lambda which access to two objects, and compares attributes (if the access modifier allows it) or functions declared for those objects.

Comment: Any letter is codified using an standard, the most common are ASCII or UNICODE, the comparison is done using its numerical value and it is handled by the `Comparator`

Comment: In a binary search must exist an order, it works in analogy as a binary tree does.